# SameSite Cookie Setting using IdentityServer3 - Can't replicate expected issue

Tags: asp.net, google-chrome, cookies, identityserver3, samesite

We have a security application that is built using IdentityServer3 utilising the hybrid flow.  A number of other APIs and front end applications connect to this central security application.

We've learned recently that the SameSite cookie setting being introduced in Chrome 80 will cause issues by settings the `SameSite=Lax` option by default however I've tried to mimic this error using the beta version of Chrome 80, one of the front end applications and the security application and do not see any error.

[screenshot of cookies with no SameSite setting on Chrome 80 Beta](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DwJZ.png)

What kind of requests will cause this error?

Comment: In case you haven't already, please read [this post](https://leastprivilege.com/2020/01/05/identityserver3-and-upcoming-samesite-cookie-changes-in-browsers/)

Answer (score 0):

The new SameSite features need to be enabled in chrome://flags: same-site-by-default-cookies and cookies-without-same-site-must-be-secure.

Comment: I have tried with them settings manually enabled (even though they are enabled by default in Chrome 80 beta)

Comment: They are not enabled by default in Chrome 80 beta. You still need to set the flags in Chrome 80.